# How to match a character in middle or at the end of string but only once

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string in Java with String.matches().

Accepted values are

- ABC321,
- ABC321/OTHER888
- or ABC321/

but

- /ABC321
- or ABC321/OTHER888/

should not match.

So `/` may be in middle or at the end of the string but not at the beginning and it should appear only once.

This is the closest regexp I have managed to do:

```
myString.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]+/?$");
```

but the problem is that / may appear multiple times. So how can I improve the regex to allow / only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that you allow `/` at least 2 times with `/?`.

You need to only allow the `/` once.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Also, `matches` requires a full string match, no need to use `^` and `$` anchors in this regex if you only plan to use it with `matches`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/SE3hDx)

```
System.out.println("ABC321".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
System.out.println("ABC321/OTHER888".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
System.out.println("ABC321/".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
System.out.println("/ABC321".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
System.out.println("ABC321/OTHER888/".matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+/?[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\/{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

`{0,1}` ensures appearance of '/' minimum 0 times and maximum 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a negative look ahead to assert only 1 slash, and keep the rest simple:

```
if (str.matches("(?!.*/.*/)\\w[\\w/]+"))
```

See (equivalent) [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/wtbx43EjaQ).